# Unresolved external symbol for type traits template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-studio-2015, type-traits

I have the following code which I use for implementing [Tag Dispatching](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching):

```
template <class T> struct tag
{
    typedef struct {} type;
   static const type value;
};
```

I then use this struct in several definitions for providing overloaded versions of functions that, for some reason, could be ambiguous. For instance, I have a set of `unarchive` functions that take a single parameter `unarchiver ar`. The type that follows uses type traits for deciding the overloaded version to use, thus determining what type to unarchive. Here's an example that unarchives packets:

```
packet HYP_NAMESPACE unarchive(unarchiver ar, typename tag<packet>::type)
{
    // Code here
}
```

This can be called like so:

```
unarchive(ar, tag<packet>::value);
```

This code works fine with both gcc and clang, but it's failing in VS 2015. I just get a bunch of errors like:

> LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static struct tag::type const tag::value" (?value@?$tag@G@@2Utype@12@B)

The `struct tag` declaration is in a header (.h) of its own, and the usages appear all over implementation (.cpp) files. Can anyone identify the cause for this?

Comment: Where do you explicitly define your static member  variable?

Comment: Hm.. Didn't think of that. I don't. In this case I don't need a specific value for initialization, if it contains trash it should be fine. You think that's causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `static const type value;` is a declaration of the static member variable `value`, it is a promis that the variable will be defined somewhere else.

This: `template <class T> const typename tag<T>::type tag<T>::value;` is a definition.

The definition is more than just initialization.

Comment: Thank you Jonas. Indeed I didn't remember of initializing the variable. Funny how this works with clang and gcc (my initial targets), which led me to believe everything was OK.

Comment: Yes, both compilers will in many cases accept static member variables without a definition. But it is, as you have noticed, not very portable.

Comment: Got it! I usually only use gcc and clang, so this got me wondering. It's fixed now.

Comment: What I've always found very bizarre is that you can even initialize static member variables without a definition, and use them, and it all works, until you pass them by reference (they become "ODR used) and then the fact that you don't have a definition causes linker errors. It seems like it would just be preferable to be more restrictive.